# Determining the basis of a span of vectors for all values of $a$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, span

I'm struggling to find a solution this question, which involves a variable. I need to find the basis of the span of the following vectors: $(a,1,1), (1,a,1)$ and $(a,1,1)$ for all values of $a$. Obviously $v_1$ and $v_3$ are the same vectors for all values of $a$ so I'm left with two vectors $(a,1,1)$ and $(1,a,1)$. I understand how to find the basis of a span of vectors when dealing with all constants so this is what I have so far:

$x(a,1,1) + b(1,a,1) = (0,0,0)$

$(ax + b, x+ba, x+b) = (0,0,0)$

$x=-b$

So $(-ba + b, -b+ba, -b+b) = (0,0,0)$

$-ba+b=0$

$-ba=-b$

$a=1$

I don't even know if this is relevant and if it answers the question. What do I need to do to show a basis of a span for all values of $a$ sufficiently?

Comment: $(a, 1, 1)$ and $(1,a,1)$ _are_ the basis of what they span. (They are linearly independent and they span the vectorspace.) Do you want an orthonormal basis of something?

Answer (score 0):

Put the vectors as rows of the matrix and do the row reduction to get

$\pmatrix{
 a & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & a & 1 \\}\rightarrow 
\pmatrix{
1 & a & 1 \\
 a & 1 & 1 \\}\rightarrow
\pmatrix{
1 & a & 1 \\
 0 & 1-a^2 & 1-a \\}\rightarrow
\pmatrix{
1 & a & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & \frac1{1+a} \\}\rightarrow
\pmatrix{
 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{a+1} \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{a+1} \\
}$

conclude that for $a\ne1$ the vectors are linearly independent and therefore form a basis for a given subspace. For $| a|\ne1$ the rows of the final matrix are the basis you looking for. For $a=-1$ the basis is $(1,-1,1),(0,0,1)$ and for the case $a=1$ the basis is $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: I believe you have a sign error here. Notice that if $a=-1$ they are independent, but if $a=1$ they are not.